# Delete data from big replicated table

Tags: sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

I have a table with more than million rows. I need to copy data to temporary table, make changes to table structure and copy back all data. This table is on transactional replication. And I wanted to know how deleting and copying data will affect the replicated data. If I will turn off the replication, will the data in replicated table be deleted and copied back?

Comment: How drastic a change are you making to the table structure? `ALTER TABLE` statements are fully supported by replication

Comment: @matigo, the changes must be done through application not db. and fails beacuse of the data in table. So the only option I see is to delete data in table, make changes through application and restore the data. But I don't want any changes on replicated table

Comment: Performing drastic work on a pair of tables on a publisher with none of those transactions sent through to the subscriber? That is outside of something I've done with SQL Server since Shiloh. Will have to step back on this one ...

Comment: @matigo, I mean data removal and restoration shoudn't be performed on subscriber. Change is structure of course will be replicated. There will not be any changes on data

Comment: What is the exact error you get when the change is attempted in the application? Depending on what you're trying to do, you might have to remove the table in question from your **Publication's Articles**, make the change, and then add it back to the **Publication's Articles**. No need to `DELETE` data or use a **TempTable** for this (which likely wouldn't fix your error).